# ssh Permission denied only in cron job

Tags: bash, ssh, cron

Having a very strange problem. I've created a small bash script which runs a command on a remote host via ssh (using public key authentication).

When I run this script manually from the command line it works fine, but when placed in /etc/cron.hourly it fails with `Permission denied, please try again.` error.

- I explicitly set the key in the script using `ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa user@remote "command"`;
- the script is running as root (I added a `` echo `id` > /tmp/whoami.log `` to double-check); and
- the ssh key is not password protected...

The system is Ubuntu 12.04 server, I don't have much access on the remote side to troubleshoot, but as I said, running ssh manually or the same bash script from the command-line works.

Any idea why this is happening or how to fix it??

### update

turns out I was mistaken, and the ssh key *was* password protected (with keychain loading the ssh-agent), hence why it failed from a script but not when running from the bash session. Adding `. ~/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh` to my script resolved the problem (thanks to @grawity who pointed me in the right direction and provided a comprehensive answer).

Comment: Are you sure running it manually uses that particular key? Test again after unsetting `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `KRB5CCNAME` environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Not sure I understand you fully though. I am pretty sure it is using that particular key, because I am able to connect / run a command on the remote host when running manually. What exactly should I test again after unsetting those variables?

Comment: Also - I'm not using ssh-agent, so not sure how `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is related (although I'm happy to try anything). I'm accessing the key file directly, and the key file is not password protected. As for `KRB5CCNAME` a quick search showed this is something to do with Kerberos. Again - don't see the connection to this problem, but maybe I'm missing something here...

Comment: Test your script, of course. You cannot be "pretty sure it is using that particular key" until you do so, because cron jobs run in a different environment than interactive commands. It would be even better if you added a `-v` option to that `ssh` command...

Comment: But I do so. I explicitly use the key using `ssh -i` command in both cases... I'll try unsetting those variables in the script and see. Good suggestion to add `-v` - I'll add it too.

Comment: You have not mentioned whether you have any kind of SSH agent running or not, so I'm just guessing the possible differences between manual and cron environments. In particular: The `ssh` client always tries agent keys *before* the one explicitly specified. So it is *possible* that your script, when run manually, only uses the agent and never reaches the explicitly-specified key. Meanwhile, cron jobs do not have access to the agent, and only try the specified key. This is why I am asking to unset `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and re-do a manual test.

Comment: The same applies to Kerberos. I do not know anything about your environment, and don't know whether it actually uses Kerberos or not. But *if* it does, then `ssh` would try a Kerberos ticket before using SSH keys; and again, cronjobs do not have access to user's Kerberos tickets. Adding one `unset ...` line is not hard.

Comment: Bingo! It looks like it is the ssh agent... I forgot it *was* running (via keychain when I login...doh!). Thanks @grawity !! If you put it as answer I'd be happy to accept it. And if you add tips on accessing the agent from cron - even better :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interactive commands and cron jobs run in different environments – in particular, **an interactive session might have a SSH agent running, or a Kerberos TGT stored.** Because of the way `ssh` orders authentication methods, you *cannot* be sure that your key is used just because you added the `-i` option.

- If a SSH agent is running, the `ssh` client always tries agent keys *before* using any explicitly-specified keys.
- If the network uses Kerberos and a Kerberos TGT is present, OpenSSH will use it *before* trying public-key authentication.

I don't know anything about your environment, but both of these possibilities are easy to check:

1. Add `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `unset KRB5CCNAME` before the `ssh` command, *then* manually run the modified script.

   This will prevent the script from seeing the agent or the Kerberos tickets, and will only use the explicitly-specified key.
2. Add the `-v` option to `ssh`. This will display more detail on how the authentication happens.

You can also add `-oIdentitiesOnly=yes` to the `ssh` command; this will [force it to use the specified key](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config).

---

> And if you add tips on accessing the agent from cron - even better

This is generally not recommended, since the agent is usually closely tied to your interactive login session. In particular, it's only started when you log in, and killed when you log out – and it needs your password to actually unlock the SSH keys (assuming they were password-protected).

You mentioned "Keychain" – is this the OS X program, or the Linux script? (I don't know much about the architecture of Mac OS X, but AFAIK it makes it *much* harder to access the user's ssh-agent from a cronjob...)

Comment: You can use ssh-cron to set up scheduled SSH connections to secure servers without exposing your SSH keys, but using SSH agent. https://superuser.com/questions/463540/ssh-permission-denied-only-in-cron-job/1108416#1108416

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround to this issue is set cron to ssh to the local box to in turn run the ssh command instead of running the file or command by its local, absolute path.  This caches the KRB5CCNAME and works where /path/command does not.

```
# Fails:
0 * * * * /home/user/sshscript.sh

# Works:
0 * * * * /usr/bin/ssh user@localhost /home/user/sshscript.sh

#!/bin/bash
# Works:
unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK
unset KRB5CCNAME
/usr/bin/ssh user@localhost /home/user/sshscript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ssh-cron](https://github.com/fbb-git/ssh-cron) to set up scheduled SSH connections to secure servers without exposing your SSH keys, but using SSH agent.

Comment: The dependencies aren't available on Homebrew, so installing seems to be complicated. Passwordless key I guess… :-/

Answer (score -1):

you can run your script or command in crontab like:

0 * * * * bash -c -l "/home/user/sshscript.sh"

or

0 * * * * bash -c -l "ssh root@yourhost 'echo $HOSTNAME'"

Comment: OP is already trying to run the script via `cron`; so this doesn't really seem to provide an answer.